# Можно ли растянуть дочерний блок, по размерам родительского?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, scss, nextjs

Делаю кнопку в Next.js:

```css
.button_nav{
  border-radius: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  &::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: $orange;
    height: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  &:hover{
    &::before{
      margin-top: -50%;
      margin-left: -30%;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import styles from "@/app/styles/UI/buttons/button_NavBar.module.scss"
import Link from "next/link";
interface ButtonNavBar {
    href: string;
    title: string;
}
const ButtonNavBar: React.FC<ButtonNavBar> = ({href, title}) => {
    return (
        <button className={`${styles.button_nav} px-6 py-2`}>
            {title}
            <Link href={href}/>
        </button>
    );
};

export default ButtonNavBar;
```

На самом сайте, появляется тег а, это понятно, в Next.js это Link. Но при этом, тег а почему-то в высоту 18 пикселей, а мне нужно чтобы на всю ширину блока он был, это делается для возможности перехода по страницами и блокам
Как это сделать? Заранее благодарю

Comment: `тег а почему-то в высоту 18 пикселей, а мне нужно чтобы на всю ширину блока он был` -- что не так с высотой, если Вам нужна ширина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Растяните ссылку на всю кнопку. (я так понимаю именно этого вы и хотите?)

```
a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю!
Действительно, с такими стилями, дочерний блок растягивается на размер родительского